# Using `mathastext` or `newtxmath`

Tags: newtx, mathastext

Is it more appropriate to use `tgtermes` with `mathastext` and option `italic` or to use `newtxtext` and `newtxmath`? I do not know if one of them is missing some functionality for math mode. I would like to have math mode typeset in times new roman, with italics. Both of the package options seem to support this, but I do not know which is more appropriate.

Comment: `newtxmath` provides a full fledged set of math symbols, whereas `mathastext` is essentially do-as-much-as-we-can.

Comment: Is there than other any advantage to using `mathastext` for times? Or is it mainly for use of other fonts?

Comment: `mathastext` is the last resource, in my opinion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I took the `testmath.tex` file in the distribution of `amsmath` and first added

```
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
```

This is a picture of one of its parts

[image]

Then I used

```
\usepackage{tgtermes}
\usepackage[italic]{mathastext}
```

getting

[image]

I find the latter unacceptable, given that getting the former is possible. Notably, Greek letters are in Computer Modern and the kerning is wrong. The partial derivative symbol is too wide for Times.

Of course one might not like the `newtxmath` integrals, but there is the option for substituting them (`cmintegrals`).

As a general rule, `mathastext` should be considered the last resort.